# Is $(\phi\implies\psi) \iff ((\phi\land\psi)\lor \neg\phi) $ provable in the following hilbert calculus without contraposition or reductio?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, provability, hilbert-calculus

Is $(\phi\implies \psi) \iff ((\phi\land \psi)\lor \neg \phi) $ in the following hilbert calculus without contraposition or reductio ad absurdum? If so, how would I go about proving it, and if not, how would I prove that it is not derivable?

Inference Rules: Modus Ponens

Axioms:

$\phi \implies (\psi \implies \phi)$

$(\phi \implies (\chi \implies \psi)) \implies ((\phi \implies \chi) \implies (\phi \implies \psi))$

$(\phi \land \psi)\implies\phi; (\phi \land \psi) \implies \psi $

$\phi \implies (\psi \implies (\phi \land \psi)) $

$\phi \implies (\phi \lor \psi); \psi \implies (\phi \lor \psi) $

$(\phi \implies \psi) \implies ((\chi \implies \psi) \implies ((\phi \lor \chi) \implies \psi)) $

Biimplication is defined as usual.

$\phi\iff\neg\neg\phi $

$\neg (\phi \land \psi) \iff (\neg \phi \lor \neg \psi) $

$\neg (\phi \lor \psi) \iff (\neg \phi \land \neg \psi) $

$\phi \lor \neg \phi $

[Here is my current attempt at proving one side of the conditional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GJQN.png)

Comment: The formula in the title of your question is not the same as the one in the body. As regards your question, finding proofs for this kind of thing in a Hilbert calculus is usually fairly tedious and IMO the best way is to see if you can transform the Hilbert calculus into a more tractable sequent calculus and then work in the sequent calculus (this typically involves proving the deduction theorem). Proving that a formula is not provable usually involves building models.

Comment: @RobArthan I fixed the title. I'm not familiar with sequent calculi, do you know a resource about them that would help?

Comment: Well you could have a look at the Wikipedia page on [sequent calculi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus), but if you don't know about them already, it might be a big detour. Can you say a bit more about the context: is this a course problem or are you working from a textbook?

Comment: @RobArthan I'm working through a logic textbook, but this isn't from the textbook; I've been messing around with axioms trying to see the effects of removing various ones or adding ones to see how it effects what is derivable in the logic, but I've been at this for a day and I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: @PW_246 are you talking about deriving (in an assumption (x /\ y) \/ ~x)) the sentences ~x -> (x -> y) and (x /\ y) -> (x -> y) then applying LEM? if so, the problem I'm having is that ~x -> (x -> y) does not seem derivable, even though the latter is. the problem is the same inside a second assumption of x.

Comment: @TheSea I’m pretty sure you need $\neg P := (P \to \bot)$. Then, since $\bot \to ((P \to \bot) \to \bot)$ is provable, it follows that $\bot \to P$. The rest should follow pretty naturally.

Comment: @PW_246 so then without that axiom/definition is it not possible to prove? the axioms here don't have that because ~P <-> (P -> F) allows reductio etc

Comment: @PW_246 so it turned out the other side of the biconditional is not provable in a stronger system that this logic happens to be a substructural logic of, meaning it's not provable in this system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following tables satisfy the above axioms:

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejqC7.png)

{1, 2} are the designated values.

Counterexample at 2, 3. ((ϕ ∧ ψ) ∨ ¬ϕ) is designated there but (ϕ⟹ψ) is not. Therefore the other side of the biconditional is not provable in this logic. □